# IIS ARR URL Rewrite utilizing a corporate proxy to make external calls

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewrite-module, arr

I have an IIS server that serves a static app and I will also need it to pass requests to an external service (out of my control) to bypass CORS rules.

I successfully configured a simple rule in URL Rewrite that passes my relative requests to the external service. In a real environment however, the IIS server will be behind a corporate proxy which requires authentication. IIS will need to use it to access the external service.

Now, my current URL Rewrite configuration doesn't work - IIS endpoint returns Bad Gateway. I tried

```
<system.net>    
  <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">      
    <proxy usesystemdefault="True" />      
  </defaultProxy>    
</system.net>
```

and also

```
<system.net>
  <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="false">
    <module type = "Module.Proxy, Module.Proxy" />
  </defaultProxy>
</system.net>
```

together with running the IIS process as an identity that has access to the corporate proxy.

Does ARR use the `system.net` proxy settings? Is there any other way to make it work?

Comment: If you ask Google, you will see how to configure proxy settings for Windows system account. `<system.net>`, however, does not apply to your case.

Comment: This question is specifically about URL rewrite making use of either system-configured proxy one provided by an explicit piece of configuration. Otherwise the only other option I see is to use a custom code that will go through the proxy - which I wanted to avoid